# Vue 3 issues importing / resolving component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

Hi new to Vue and learning through tutorials. I have created a component Header.vue and try to import it to App.vue.
This is the structure:
[code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKxz9.png)

here is App.vue:

```js
<template>
  <Header />
</template>

<script>
import Header  from "./components/Header.vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      Header,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
}
</style>
```

Here is the Header.vue component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Income Tracker</h1>
    <div class="total-income">$0</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

};
</script>

<style scoped>
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: #313131;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ffce00;
}
header h1 {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 28px;
}
header .total-income {
  font-family: "Fira Code", "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffce00;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
</style>
```

I am getting the styling from the App.vue but the component isn't resolving. In the console I get this error:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKxz9.png)

What I have tried is stack overflow and google search based on the error message text.

Either I am not searching correctly, or I do not have enough experience at this point to identify the issue causing this problem.

Education on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend against using `Header` as a component name, since it could conflict with the HTML [`header` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header). This violates the [very first rule in the Vue Style Guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/style-guide/#priority-a-rules-essential-error-prevention).

Comment: I think this tutorial is a lil wack.. already learned more here fixing the problem the the first 4 min of the tuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register components in the `components` option.

```js
export default {
  components: {
    Header,
  },
};
```

See [the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-registration.html#local-registration-in-a-module-system).

Note that including a valueless entry in a JavaScript object (e.g. `Header`) is ES6 syntax for `Header: Header`.

Comment: Ders thank you. Your solution brought the text over which means that the component import works now. For some reason the component styling is not displaying now, but the <h1> and the <div> displays. One step further along thanks for the assist.

Comment: No problem. It is good to jump right into things because that's a great way to learn, but at some point I would recommend reading the entirety of the [Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html). They are great, and you should be referencing them a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use components like this

```
<template>
  <header />
</template>

<script>
import Header  from "./components/Header.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        "header": Header
    },
  setup() {
    return {
      Header,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Jay Patel thanks you .. but using "header":Header didnt work. In combination with your code structure and @Ders answer also I was able to move it forward.

Comment: it will work see template tag and change it accordingly like    <header /> .

Answer (score 0):

In your Header.vue replace your div tag with header tag, because you are styling header tag in your CSS and not div tag.

```
<template>
  <header>
    <h1>Income Tracker</h1>
    <div class="total-income">$0</div>
  </header>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you Amit! Every new bit of education helps. But it now displays the <h1> and the <div> but not the component styling.

Comment: In your Header.vue, you have done styling using CSS element selector i.e. <header> in your case, but you havn't used that tag in your code. So in your Header.vue, change your parent <div> tag with <header> tag.

Comment: `name` does not register components. It is useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: my bad! Thanks @Ders for bringing that to my knowledge.

Comment: Amit and @Ders Thank you both.